# Track System.Diagnostics.Trace logs in Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics

In my web application, I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...);
```

for diagnostics. The application is published to an Azure deployment slot. I am wondering where I can find these logs in the Azure Portal (or Visual Studio's cloud explorer).

Comment: Do you not have to configure the location of these logs in your web.config?

Answer (score 8):

You first need to activate the Application Logging:

1. Go to your Web App.
2. Go to `Monitoring` / `App Service logs`.
3. Enable `Application Logging` and configure it.

[image: Application Logging]

This article can also be useful: https://stackify.com/azure-app-service-log-files/

Comment: Very useful article

Comment: Where is Application logging now (the menu and options are all very different now, and search does not show that name)

Comment: Updated the screenshot with the new UI.